# Service making the $scope not accessible on the html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Can't access the scope, for example putting `{{ pagec }}` on the html isn't working but when I remove `blogpostservice` from the controller it works fine again.

```
var app = angular.module('Blog', []);

app.factory('blogpostservice', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.getMoreData = function (pagecount) {
        return $http.get('/api/posts/' + pagecount);

    }
}]);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'blogpostservice',
    function ($scope, blogpostservice) {

        $scope.pagec = 1;
        $scope.posts = [];
        this.getMoreData = function (posts) {
            blogpostservice.getMoreData(pagec).success(function () {
                alert('got it successfully!!!'); 
            }).error(function () {
                alert('something went wrong!!!');
            });
        }


    }]);
```

Comment: Hmmm «pagec» is pass to getMoreData but it's not declared. Pass $scope.pagec instead.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil still not working the problem is as soon as i remove the service from the paramters it works again, but i need the service to fetch data from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you had wrong `factory` implementation, `factory` should always return an `object`. You must have got an error in console(please check).

```
app.factory('blogpostservice', ['$http', 
  function ($http) {
    function getMoreData (pagecount) {
        return $http.get('/api/posts/' + pagecount);
    }
    return {
       getMoreData: getMoreData
    }
  }
]);
```

---

Or you can convert your `factory` to `service`, there you need to bind data to `this`(context) like your were doing before.

```
app.service('blogpostservice', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.getMoreData = function (pagecount) {
        return $http.get('/api/posts/' + pagecount);
    }
}]);
```

> Also don't use `.success`/`.error` on `$http` call, they are
>   deprecated. Instead use `.then`.

Comment: Working, great to know this new info, for the success or error on the controller doesn't then create a new promise? isn't it bad?